# html - Replace Input Radio with Text

Tags: html, css

I would like to replace the 'input radio' with text, and that it changes color when selected.

The default color is white #FFFFFF, but when clicked, it changes to #627CA9 but without visible 'radio input'.

I would like the circle of the 'input radio' to become 'display: none' but keep a text, which when the user clicks, changes color, giving an idea that the 'input radio' has been clicked

I don't know if it will be possible to do this!
Thank you in advance for your help!
(Sorry My English)

```
<label><input type="radio" name="poll_option" class="poll_option" value="CHVRCHES">CHVRCHES</label>
```

Comment: question is not clear plz explain properly

Comment: I would like the circle of the 'input radio' to become 'display: none' but keep a text, which when the user clicks, changes color, giving an idea that the 'input radio' has been clicked

Comment: Does my answer do what you want? Or do you want the radio button hidden from the start?

Comment: Yes that's right! however, it appears before it is clicked

Comment: @SergioC What appears before it's clicked?

Comment: The 'input radio'. At the start of the page it would have to be invisible too

Comment: @SergioC Check my updated answer. But is there any point in having the radio button in the first place? You'd be better off omitting it and using a `onclick` event for a `p` or `span` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? I've used jQuery to hide the radio button and change the label's colour when the radio button is clicked.

```js
function changeInput(input) {
  $(input).hide();
  $(input).parent().css('color', '#627CA9');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" onclick="changeInput(this);" name="poll_option" class="poll_option" value="CHVRCHES">CHVRCHES</label>
```

If you want the radio button hidden from the start:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.poll_option').hide();
});

function changeInput(input) {
  $(input).parent().css('color', '#627CA9');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" onclick="changeInput(this);" name="poll_option" class="poll_option" value="CHVRCHES">CHVRCHES</label>
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly how I want it! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help, just need some extra span:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="poll_option" class="poll_option"value="CHVRCHES">
  <span>CHVRCHES</span>
</label>
```

and

```
.label input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

.label input[type="radio"]:checked+span {
  color: #627CA9;
}
```